# Got an javascript issue with cart page, adding and removing items gives an error

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce

I have been studying python language and started to make my own e-commerce website with Django. Unfortunately I don't  know javascript and copied all the code for cart page. And it's not working:

[image: None of these buttons are working and give an error message]

[image: These errors]

Here is cart.js code:
(and honestly I don't know what's wrong with that)

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
        console.log('USER:', user)

        if (user === 'AnonymousUser'){
            addCookieItem(productId, action)
        }else{
            updateUserOrder(productId, action)
        }
    })
}

function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

        var url = 'update_item/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        .then((response) => {
           return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
}

function addCookieItem(productId, action){
    console.log('User is not authenticated')

    if (action === 'add'){
        if (cart[productId] === undefined){
        cart[productId] = {'quantity':1}

        }else{
            cart[productId]['quantity'] += 1
        }
    }

    if (action === 'remove'){
        cart[productId]['quantity'] -= 1

        if (cart[productId]['quantity'] <= 0){
            console.log('Item should be deleted')
            delete cart[productId];
        }
    }
    console.log('CART:', cart)
    document.cookie ='cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"

    location.reload()
}
```

Here is cart.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% extends 'main.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Cart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="box-element">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'store' %}">&#x2190;continue shopping</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th><h5>Items: <strong>{{order.get_cart_items}}</strong></h5></th>
                        <th><h5>Total: <strong>{{order.get_cart_total}}</strong></h5></th>
                        <th>
                            <a style="float: right; margin: 5px" class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'checkout' %}">Checkout</a>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="box-element">
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex: 2"></div>
                    <div style="flex: 2"><strong>item</strong></div>
                    <div style="flex: 1"><strong>price</strong></div>
                    <div style="flex: 1"><strong>quantity</strong></div>
                    <div style="flex: 1"><strong>total</strong></div>
                </div>
                {% for item in items %}
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex: 2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.image.url}}"></div>
                    <div style="flex: 2">{{item.product.name}}</div>
                    <div style="flex: 1">{{item.product.price}}</div>
                    <div style="flex: 1">
                        <p class="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</p>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <img data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="add" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static 'images/arrow-up.png' %}">
                            <img data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="remove" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static 'images/arrow-down.png' %}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="flex: 1">{{item.get_total}}</div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

If anyone could assist, please help!
And thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fetch a page, where is not a json with your data.

Try to look to your

```
var url = 'update_item/'
```

and check the result like this

```
    var url = 'update_item/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        .then((response) => {
           //return response();
           console.log(response)

        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
```

As u can see on this webpage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Thank you. I'll definately take a look.